# function missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X_train' and 'y_train'

Tags: python, training-data, backpropagation

1. i'm writing Python with Jupyter notebook in reference and having this kind of error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3a2267df06a1> in <module>
      1 # Section II: First run the backpropagation simulation
----> 2 model_s = vanilla_backpropagation()

TypeError: vanilla_backpropagation() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X_train' and 'y_train'
```

2. it caused when I try to run this:

```
# Section II: First run the backpropagation simulation
model_s = vanilla_backpropagation()
```

3. here's the code for that vanilla_backpropagation function and split the training testing

```
def vanilla_backpropagation(X_train, y_train):
    best_model = None
    best_score = 100.00
    
    for i in range(N):
        model_s = build_ann(LOSS)
        model_s.fit(X_train, 
                    y_train,
                    epochs = STEPS,
                    batch_size = batch_size,
                    verbose = 0)
        train_score = model_s.evaluate(X_train, y_train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, verbose = 0)
        if train_score > best_score:
            best_model = model_s
            best_score = train_score
    return best_model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Section I: Build the data set
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, shuffle = None)
```

can anyone help with this error? am stuck with it for over days now. thankyou

Comment: You've defined a function called `vanilla_backpropagation()` that requires two parameters but provided zero.

Comment: other thing - what's `build_ann` ? You need to ensure code is 100% reproducible for us (so we can copy paste the code you provided into our ide, and get exactly the same error message).

Answer (score 1):

When you defining a function with some inputs, you need to provide those inputs to the function when calling it. After splitting your data in the last line of the main function

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, shuffle = None)
```

You can call your function like

```
vanilla_backpropagation(X_train, y_train)
```

It seems that you are new to both python and Deep Learning. Please read related documentation and examples to first learn how to train a network and use python functions.

Comment: i try to call the function like the statement above but it took longer than expected

Comment: Because based on what I understand from your backpropagation function, you try to train a (deep) model, fit and evaluate it on a data. Depending on your dataset and the task you trying to do, it can take a long time and consume too much memory.